# TypeORM / NestJS - @BeforeUpdate hook not working

Tags: javascript, nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm, nestjs-config

I'm having problems using TypeOrm hook "BeforeUpdate"

I'm trying to update the user entity password, by passing a simple string and calling the save method to trigger the beforeUpdate hook and then hash the password, but this hook is not working while calling the save method.

This is what i have

**user.service.ts**

```js
async update(id: number, updateUserDto: UpdateUserDto) {
  const roles =
    updateUserDto.roles &&
    (await Promise.all(
      updateUserDto.roles.map((name) => this.preloadRoleByName(name))
    ));
  const user = await this.userRepository.findOneOrFail(id);
  if (!user) {
    throw new NotFoundException(`User with ID #${id} not found`);
  }
  const toSaveUser = {
    ...user,
    ...updateUserDto,
    roles,
  };
  return await this.userRepository.save(toSaveUser);
}
```

**user.entity.ts**

```js
.
.
.
@Column()
@Exclude()
password: string;

@BeforeInsert()
@BeforeUpdate()
private async hashPassword() {
  const rounds = 10;
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(rounds);
  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
}
```

**user.controller.ts**

```js
@Patch(":id")
@UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
async update(@Param("id") id: string, @Body() updateUserDto: UpdateUserDto) {
 return await this.usersService.update(+id, updateUserDto);
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

`BeforeInsert` hook works or if I call `userRepository.preload()` method to update it works but it doesn't replace the relationship of the role, that's why I take this approach.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Something to be aware of when using the triggers is that they might require instances of the entity to run.

`Problem:`

```
const user = await this.userRepository.findOneOrFail(id); // entity instance
const toSaveUser = { ...user, ...updateUserDto, roles }; // plain object
return await this.userRepository.save(toSaveUser); // not running trigger
```

`Solution:`

```
const user = await this.userRepository.findOneOrFail(id); // entity instance
// still entity instance
const toSaveUser = this.userRepository.create({
  ...user,
  ...updateUserDto,
  roles,
});
return await this.userRepository.save(toSaveUser); // running trigger
```

And you should be good.

Since you are using `repository.save()` with an arbitrary object in your code, the trigger does not run. If we instead use `repository.create()` to create the instance, the trigger will now run.

The reason why your solution worked with `repository.preload()` is because it returns an instance. [Repository api examples](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/repository-api.md)

Answer (score 2):

You need to create DTO(Data Transfer Object) first and then update. this code is for update temporary password.

How create DTO:

```js
this.<YOUR_REPOSITORY_NAME>.create(<INPUT_OBJECT>)
```

Example:

```js
async updatePassword(id: number, tempPassword: string): Promise<boolean> {
    let newUser = { tempPassword: tempPassword };
    const userDto = this.userAccountRepository.create(newUser)
    const userAccount = this.userAccountRepository.update(
      {
        userAccountId: id,
      },
      userDto 
    );
    if (userAccount) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

This is my entity:

```js
import {
  BeforeInsert,
  BeforeUpdate,
  Column,
  Entity,
  JoinColumn,
  OneToMany,
  OneToOne,
  PrimaryColumn,
  } from 'typeorm';
import { Users } from '../users/users.entity';
const crypto = require('crypto');

    @Entity()
    export class UserAccount {
      @PrimaryColumn()
      userAccountId: number;
      @OneToOne(() => Users, { cascade: true })
      @JoinColumn({ name: 'userAccountId' })
      @Column({ nullable: true })
      tempPassword: string;
      @BeforeInsert()
      @BeforeUpdate()
      async hashPassword(): Promise<void> {
        if (!!this.password) {
          this.password = crypto.createHmac('sha256', this.password).digest('hex');
        }
        if (!!this.tempPassword) {
          this.tempPassword = crypto
            .createHmac('sha256', this.tempPassword)
            .digest('hex');
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Two inputs from my side,

1. Separate function for encrypting updated password -

> ```
>   @BeforeUpdate()
>   async hashPasswordBeforeUpdate() {
>     this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10);
>   }
> ```

2. Try creating `PUT` request instead of a `PATCH` request

I am able to generate a valid update query, sharing just for reference-

```
query: UPDATE `users` SET `levelId` = ?, `updatedAt` = ?, `password` = ? WHERE `id` IN (?) -- PARAMETERS: [null,"2021-05-07T07:27:47.198Z","$2b$10$uQOMNv57BZLB/W/9SWPbke6/OMdIDWxv3i25A8rUhA0/vEMloWb2W",1]
```